# Friend can’t join my Minecraft world on PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Whenever I invite my friend she doesn’t get the invite and when she send an invite I can’t see the invite and sometimes we can’t join each others worlds

Answer (score 1):

Usually a notification pops up try to invite when the one device is off and press the notification OR see if Xbox didn’t sign you out and your Minecraft is the same update version.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that:
1. You need the same internet
2. The internet is slowing down
3. You don’t have the same version of Minecraft PE.
4. You might not be playing on PE.

Answer (score -1):

There could be two reasons that I can think of straight away 
1. you don’t have the same update as your friend 
2. You are not connected two the same internet

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems so I restarted my device and it was working again.